# Adding an extra SQL select statement is returning too many results

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables that all need to interact. They are for a bike inventory. They are bike shop, shop inventory, and bike model. I want to find the cheapest bike in each shop inventory. The code below gives me the correct result I expect, but I also want to show the bike name.

```
SELECT 
    BS.BIKESHOPNAME, MIN(BM.PRICE)
FROM 
    BIKESHOP BS, BIKEMODEL BM, SHOPINVENTORY SI
WHERE 
    SI.BIKESHOPID = BS.BIKESHOPID  
    AND SI.BIKEID = BM.BIKEID
GROUP BY 
    BS.BIKESHOPNAME;
```

If I change the select statement to look like:

```
SELECT BS.BIKESHOPNAME, BM.NAME, MIN(BM.PRICE)
```

I get too many results. Do I have to check that the name matches the bike model?

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm

Comment: Well I just started learning, but I'm having trouble doing a JOIN with 3 tables.

Comment: You do a JOIN with 3 tables exactly like you do a JOIN with 2 tables or 4 tables. `FROM BikeShop bs INNER JOIN ShopInventory si on si.BikeShopID = bs.BikeShopID INNER JOIN <someothertable><alias> on <alias.column> = <source.column> INNER JOIN <table3><table3alias> on <table3alias.column> = <someothertable.column>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should solve your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
BS.BIKESHOPNAME,
FIRST_VALUE(BM.NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY BS.BIKESHOPNAME ORDER BY BM.PRICE ASC),
FIRST_VALUE(BM.PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY BS.BIKESHOPNAME ORDER BY BM.PRICE ASC)
FROM BIKESHOP BS, BIKEMODEL BM, SHOPINVENTORY SI
WHERE SI.BIKESHOPID = BS.BIKESHOPID AND SI.BIKEID = BM.BIKEID
```

I'm not sure that this is the best solution but i think it will do. It can also be solved using sub-queries but I think this one is better.

**UPDATE:**
you can use sub-queries like this:

```
    SELECT 
    BS.BIKESHOPNAME
    (SELECT TOP 1 BM.NAME FROM BIKEMODEL BM, SHOPINVENTORY SII WHERE SII.BIKEID = BM.BIKEID AND SI.BIKESHOPID = BS.BIKESHOPID ORDER BY BM.PRICE ASC) BIKENAME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 BM.PRICE FROM BIKEMODEL BM, SHOPINVENTORY SII WHERE SII.BIKEID = BM.BIKEID AND SI.BIKESHOPID = BS.BIKESHOPID ORDER BY BM.PRICE ASC) PRICE
FROM 
    BIKESHOP BS
```

Comment: That's the best answer, but it won't work for some databases like MySQL.

Comment: Great this did fix the problem. Would it be possible to see an example using sub-queries as that was what I had been attempting, and OVER is a little beyond what I've learned at this point.

Comment: @user3769402 I updated the answer with the sub-queries example

Comment: @Gubr : cost of this query is very high.

Comment: @Jigar Which one ?! the one with the sub-query?!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try maybe? This is an example of how you can use **join** as well :)

```
SELECT BS.BIKESHOPNAME, MIN(BM.PRICE), BM.NAME
FROM 
BIKESHOP AS BS

INNER JOIN 
SHOPINVENTORY AS SI
ON SI.BIKESHOPID = BS.BIKESHOPID

INNER JOIN 
BIKEMODEL AS BM
ON BM.BIKEID = SI.BIKEID

GROUP BY BS.BIKESHOPNAME, BM.NAME;
```

Comment: So after the comment above I actually changed my code to look like yours, but adding in BM.NAME still shows all the bike models in inventory.

Comment: Are the bike name repetitions? or is it differenct bike name but same price?

Comment: Well it's different inventory for different shops, but they could have the same bike, although the bike ID is unique per bike(like a serial #), if that answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

Group by is applied on bikeshopname only. Include

> Group by bs.bikeshopname,bm.name

in the end of SQL query. This should work.

Comment: That actually adds more rows, similar to adding the extra select.

Comment: @user3769402 see the records. I believe that is what you want.

Comment: If you do not group by bike name then you will see same record again and again and your count would be definitely higher.

Comment: select count(1) from ( query1 ) // query 1 is your original query. And check the same for query 2 by firing select count(1) from ( query2 ).//query with group by on bike name